# send each user their own individual emailed PDF report in Access

Tags: email, ms-access, pdf, vba, report

I've looked up the following code from another question on this site and have tried to apply it to my own, to no avail - I am trying to email out a pdf of my report to each user with only their specific information contained therein. If there are 15 users, then there will be 15 different emails sent out containing only their info. any help is very much appreciated.

```vba
Option Compare Database


Sub Mac1()
Dim rsAccountNumber As DAO.Recordset

Set rsAccountNumber = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset( _
    "SELECT DISTINCT AccountNumber FROM UnAffirmed_Report_for_En Query")

With rsAccountNumber

    Do Until .EOF

        DoCmd.OpenReport "Unaffirmed Report", _
            acViewPreview, _
            WhereCondition:="AccountNumber = " & !AccountNumber, _
            WindowMode:=acHidden

        DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, _
            "Unaffirmed Report", _
            acFormatPDF, _
            "C:\users\rv\folder_name" & !AccountNumber & ".pdf"

        DoCmd.Close acReport, "Unaffirmed Report", acSaveNo

        .MoveNext

    Loop

    .Close

End With
End Sub
```

when I do though, I receive Run-time error '3075':

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'AccountNumber = 1RV80014'

the account # is valid, but not sure why I am getting stuck here or how to fix it - super newbe to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your account number is a String **1RV80014** and your `Where condition:="AccountNumber = " & !AccountNumber` states an Integer. So change it to a String `Where condition:= "AccountNumber = '" & !AccountNumber & "'"`